# What is the proposed ETH 2.0 staking reward and minimum / maximum stake one can put on a node?

Tags: proof-of-stake

There are 80+ million ethereum. A staking node requires only 32 eth to stake. If even just 25% of the 80 million started to stake, that would create 625,000 staking nodes. If the reward is 1 eth per minute and split among even just 100,000 nodes. Its not worth it to stake anymore. What is the proposed staking reward per block?

And is there a min and max of how much a user can put in a ethereum staking node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the reward schedule here:
https://docs.ethhub.io/ethereum-roadmap/ethereum-2.0/eth-2.0-economics/

There is no concept of 'user'. It's 32ETH per validating node and you can run as many nodes as you want/have the resources to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Using the specifications from here: https://docs.ethhub.io/ethereum-roadmap/ethereum-2.0/eth-2.0-economics/

[image]

You need to have first a beacon node and then tie that to your validator nodes that hosts your 32ETH. You can can multiple validator nodes. Estimated cost is about $120/yr for a beacon node. And each validator node is about $60/year or $5/month.

Judging from the chart above, if 1 million eth is validating, we get a total of:

1,000,000 / 32 ETH = 31,250 validator nodes.

Currently eth 1.0 has 7400 nodes. It would need to jump up by 4x number of nodes when eth 2.0 comes online.